# Using the numeric keypad for edited shortcuts in jupyter notebook

Tags: keyboard, jupyter, shortcut, numeric, keypad

I have edited my shortcuts in Jupyter Notebook.
One of the shortcuts I created was '0,0,0'.

When I am in command mode the shortcut '0,0,0' works fine...But it only works if I use the keyboard numbers. When I try to type '0,0,0' using the zeroes on the numeric keypad, Jupyter Notebook does not recognize that I am giving it a command.

Is there a way to get it so that it will recognize numbers from both the keyboard *and* the numeric keypad? I tried searching the docs but did not find any answers.
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpad0,Numpad0,Numpad0 should work. It's using JS event codes. You can try them out here:

https://keycode.info/

Comment: Perfect! It worked, thank you. I even used your suggestion to create a shortcut that uses 'Ctrl-Numpad0'. Ordinarily this is already a separate shortcut in Chrome, but the shortcut in Jupyter Notebook successfully overrides the Chrome Shortcut.

Comment: FYI: Event codes relevant to the numeric keypad will only trigger if Num Lock is in an On state. Thus, if you accidentally turn off the Num Lock, event codes for Numpad0 or other keys on the numeric keypad will not work, and the shortcuts using those codes will likewise not work.